# How to add form as control into another form without false its toplevel property?

Tags: c#, controls

Is there any way to add a window form into another form as control? I do not want to change `TopLevel = false` while adding form as control.

OR

How can I use opacity property of added form as control when I set `TopLevel = false`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It is not possible to put a windows form inside another.

But you can initiate another form another using ShowDialog() method. It feels like that parent form calling child.

**UserControls provides the functionality add Controls on your page.**

> you can do all of this stuff with user control like opacity etc

Answer (score 2):

You can't show a form in another form. You can have this functionality very easy, if you put all the controls on a UserControl. Then show that UserControls as a single control in a form and together with other controls on another form. That's pretty much easier than to try to have a form in a form...

Answer (score 0):

Fischermaen - you can add a form to another form's control.  Create a new class, but use references for the windows form.  Make it a subclass of Form.

In the constructor you will need to edit the size and location of the form along with colors and whatever else you wish to modify.

In your main form use this:

```
this.Controls.Add(new newForm());
```